# Call ReactDOM.render in parent component `componentDidMount` lifecycle

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs, web, react-native

I am just curious about this. I write a demo below:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('ChildComponent will mount');
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ChildComponent did mount');
    }
    render() {
        console.count('ChildComponent render');
        return <div>
            ChildComponent
        </div>
    }
}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount() {
        console.log('ParentComponent will mount');
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('ParentComponent did mount')
        ReactDOM.render(
            <ChildComponent/>,
            document.getElementById('content')
        )
    }
    render() {
        console.count('ParentComponent render');
        return <div id='parent'>
            ParentComponent
            <div id='content'></div>
        </div>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ParentComponent />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

```
//normal way:
//ParentComponent will mount
//ParentComponent render: 1
//ChildComponent will mount
//ChildComponent render: 1
//ChildComponent did mount
//ParentComponent did mount

//ReactDOM.render way:
//ParentComponent will mount
//ParentComponent render: 1
//ParentComponent did mount
//ChildComponent will mount
//ChildComponent render: 1
//ChildComponent did mount
```

It seems works! But I found the difference between the two ways. The lifecycle executes order is different. But, is there any other difference? I mean, maybe there is a case that the `ReactDOM.render` the way will cause trouble or error.

I also found that if you inspect the element in browser use development tools, you will find that the `data-reactroot` property both in `ParentComponent` and `ChildComponent` root node. And the normal render way, it just disappears in `ParentComponent` root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a normal way, we will use like this.

```
<ParentComponent>
    <ChildComponent />
</ParentComponent>
```

so `ChildComponent` is a part of `ParentComponent`. so the `componentDidMount` of the child will run before the parent. only when the child has mounted, the parent will finish.

if you render `ChildComponent` in the method `ComponentDidMount` of parent. it means that `ParentComponent` doesn't include `ChildComponent`. It may seem that you use jQuery to change some content of a mounted component. so the order will be the parent will finish mount first, then the `ChildComponent`